# find all historyRequest where a status does not exist using distinct foreign key in subquery (JPA,HQL,JAVA)

Tags: java, jpa, hql

Hello everyone I have a problem writing the correct query using HQL, maybe someone can guide me in the right direction. I want to find all historyRequests based on a cvr number and where it doesn't have a specific status.

**Entities:**

```
@Data
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
@MappedSuperclass
public class AbstractEntity {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  Long id;

  @JsonFormat(shape = Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
  @CreatedDate
  LocalDateTime created;

  @JsonFormat(shape = Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
  @LastModifiedDate
  LocalDateTime modified;
}

public class HistoryRequest extends AbstractEntity {

  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinColumn(name = "history_request_id")
  private List<Status> statusList;

  @Column(name = "cvr")
  private String cvr;
}

public class Status extends AbstractEntity {

  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
  @Column(name = "event")
  private StatusEvent event;
}

@Query("select request from HistoryRequest as request where request.cvr = :cvr "
    + "AND request.id not in (SELECT DISTINCT status.historyRequestId FROM Status as status WHERE event = :event)")
List<HistoryRequest> findAllByCvrWhereStatusEventNotEqual(@Param("cvr") String cvr, @Param("event") String event);
```

i get this exception when I try to run my program:

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: historyRequestId of: com.myprojects.domain.Status
```

So I can understand from the exception that it is looking for a property in Status named historyRequestId, however it is not a property but an autogenerated column in the status table from the @JoinColumn(name = "history_request_id")

How am I supposed to deal with this if I don't want status to have any relation to historyRequest? Neither property or parent object!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: JPQL with `= ':cvr'` will interpret the last part as a String literal, rather than as a parameter. Remove the tic marks

Comment: Okay good to know.. thank you

Comment: There is no attribute historyRequestId  in the Status Entity. You are doing JPA Query. Do you want to use SQL?

Comment: Simon, I've made it work with NativeQuery regular SQL, but I wanted to know if i could do it more generic since this system runs up towards too backends with the same table names, but different table schemes..

and yes you are right, there is no property/attribute in status called historyRequestId.. That's why I'm not sure if what I'm doing is even possible or I have to stick to native queries, so instead of using sql, i wanted to do my queries on entity level.